# add xml data to http request

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am new in php programming and I would like to add data to my http request in xml format. 
I use curl to generate HTTP request using this PHP code :

```
<?php
      $fields = array(            'SERIAL_NUMBER ' => urlencode('123456'),
                            'HARDWARE_ID ' => urlencode('455FFG'),
                            'CODE ' => urlencode('99'),
                            //field goes here 
                );

      foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
      rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        $ch = curl_init("http://192.168.1.110:10000");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);                       
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $output;   

?>
```

I would like to add fields array [ SERIAL_NUMBER and HARDWARE_ID and CODE ] as data in http request in format xml

the format of the desired http request is :

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.110:10000
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 52
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue //server responce

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Device Parameters>
     <SERIAL_NUMBER>123456</SERIAL_NUMBER>
     <HARDWARE_ID>455FFG</HARDWARE_ID>
     <CODE>99</CODE>
    </Device Parameters>
```

Note : my server listen to port 10000 @ 192.168.1.110

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleXMLElement.
Represents an element in an XML document.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php